# Visual and Text tabs missing from Editor

Tags: visual-editor, text, tabs

I have two WordPress servers installed with an identical server and WordPress configurations (same  WordPress version, same PHP version, same plugins and same theme). The point is that the Visual and Text tabs do not appear in one and in the other they do. As much as I look, I don't know where the problem is or the difference between them. Any indication that can help me? I leave you the screenshots so that what I explain looks good.
We are using WordPress 5.7.2
Regards,
Pedro
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be one of 2 things:

1. This could be because for some reason the tabs were disabled. To enable it log into your WordPress admin > WordPress Main Menu > Users > Edit(user with the issue) > First Option Top of Screen is “Visual Editor”> Unchecked the box > clicked save, and everything will be fixed.
2. If 1 doesn't work then it is most likely a conflict with either your plugins or themes. You can check this and locate the problem if you disable all plugins and turn them on one by one while checking to see which one is problematic. Also to see if the theme is causing the issue just pick some of the default wp themes.

I googled for some more information and this is what I found if you want to check for yourself [link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/askrubi/permalink/393214022313711/), [link](https://wpmantis.com/fix-missing-visual-and-text-tabs-in-pagepost-editor/), [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/visual-text-tabs-missing-in-text-editor/).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this problem, just as a reminder, because I didn't think to try this, clear your browser cache. Seems too simple, I know, but it actually brought the tabs back for me on Firefox 115.